# Javascript: finding a function's code

Tags: javascript, html

This is one of the first time's I'm looking at javascript, so please excuse the newbish question.

I'm trying to read the code for a specific function on a website that is of interest to me. I didn't write anything for the website, so cannot really comment on the general structure. This is almost like reverse engineering. Where it's called (in a js/main.js) looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').funcA();
```

From what I understand this is saying from the file/class or whatever that comesf rom the id search, call funcA. My questions is: how do I see the file that is called with #search?

Comment: `$` is a function. So the function `$` is called with argument `#search`. There are several javascript libraries that use `$` as a function but given your code I strongly suspect that the library is `jQuery`. Google `jQuery`. You can try reading the source if you want but most people just read the documentation for jQuery. The source is fairly complex.

Comment: Also, in general javascript has no notion of per-file module (except for node.js). So which file something comes from depends more on who wrote the function or object. Look at all files included in `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

`funcA` is almost certainly a jQuery plugin (or part of jQuery itself). The first thing I would try in your situation is searching for "jQuery funcA" on Google.

Whether or not it is actually part of jQuery, you can see the source for that function by running:

```
$('#search').funcA
```

in a REPL, such as your browser's console, or:

```
console.log( $('#search').funcA );
```

as long as the `toString` function for that function hasn't been overwritten and it is not a reference to a native function.

Answer (score 0):

`funcA` appears to be defined as a jQuery method; try

```
console.log($.fn.funcA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open javascript console in the same browser window (I used chrome) that is displaying the page that contains that code. Then just execute this line:

```
> $('#search').funcA
```

You should see the body of `funcA`. Random example output when I did $("#myownid").show:

> function funcA (a,b,c){var d,e;if(a||a===0)return
>   this.animate(cu("show",3),a,b,c);for(var
>   g=0,h=this.length;g
>   ...

If you manage to see the body of the function, you should be able to infer likely sources (or post them here and we should be able to point you further)

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` suggestions here are nice use of [Function.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)  *(and in some browsers some console magic)*, but I'd use `debugger` instead. Chrome has quite nice debugging tools for stuff like this and the [debugger statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) will get you there with ease.

```
 var test = $('#search').funcA;
 debugger;
```

Open the console and start investigating. When the execution of your code hits that breakpoint, you'll see handy tools like this

[image]

Right-clicking `test` there should also give you the option to *"Show function definition"* which will show you where the function was actually defined as source code.

And if you want to investigate even further from there, you can always set similar breakpoints [right from the Chrome dev console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints#add-a-manual-breakpoint-on-a-single-line-of-code).

Comment: Other browsers most likely have similar tools too, but I have most experience with Chrome so I can only recommend the debugging tools in that.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Open the console and run $("#search") it will return a jquery object containing the dom node that has an id of search.

Long version:

$("something") 
Is jquery (a java script library) for select elements by css selector returning a jquery object. 
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

$(document).ready(function() {
Is jquery for when my document (basically the page) is ready for me to muck with run this anonymous function.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

$('#search').funcA();
Selects a set of elements, in this case the single element with id "search" and then run funcA on each of them using the element as the scope. So it would run funcA on the element with ID "search" with the search node being the value of the special scope variable (scope is referenced through the key word "this", it can get rather complex).

So in essence what your seeing is:
When my document is ready find the search element and run my function funcA on it.